# Layout implementation

Tags: android, layout

I wanted to design a UI like this,
[image]

But i am unable to add those buttons at the bottom and i am not getting how to bring textview in centre.

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/poster"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="158dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="158dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView" 
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    ></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

     <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="button1" 
        android:id="@+id/button1button"></Button>

      <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="button2" 
        android:id="@+id/button1button2"></Button>

       <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="button3" 
        android:id="@+id/button1button3"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here how the output looks.please help me what is the changes to be done in my code

[image]

Comment: I'd use linear **and** relative layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your parent layout to `RelativeLayout` and start alligning other views relative to each other inside. It will help you to assign views wherever you want on screen regardless of its size.

Answer (score 1):

may be this will help you, try it

```
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tblLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow1_tbllayout1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow1_txtviewspace"
                                    android:layout_width="150px"
                                    android:layout_height="20px" />

     </TableRow>
                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow1_tbllayout1_tableRow2_tbltxtviewspace"
                                    android:layout_width="30px"
                                    android:layout_height="40px" />
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableLayout>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow2_tblLayout1_tableRow2_tblLayout1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableRow
                             android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow2_tblLayout1_tableRow2_tblLayout1_tableRow2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poster"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="158dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>
                    </TableRow>   

      <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tblLayout_tableRow3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center" >



         <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="button1" 
            android:id="@+id/button1button"></Button>

          <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="button2" 
            android:id="@+id/button1button2"></Button>

           <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="button3" 
            android:id="@+id/button1button3"></Button>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Dummy text" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:src="@drawable/chilly" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="76dp"
    android:text="Dummy Text" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="202dp"
    android:text="Button3" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
    android:text="Button2" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button1" />
```